# EF 4.0 and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Can I use EF4.0 relased with .NET framework 4.0 with VS2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - EF4 is a .NET 4 only technology, and Visual Studio 2008 does not support .NET 4.